# Ok guys, I'm new to this level of review, how does re-open work?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/15243) is very vague, and they've provided a *little* more info, but really not enough. I'd like to encourage the user to get in and provide more info.

But if I click re-open, is my ONE re-open vote enough to re-open it? If i'm part of a concensus, then I'd gladly give it a go and if others thought so too then maybe he get's another shot. But on the face of it, it's not really there yet, and would only offer to re-open if others felt that "you know what, let's give the guy an extra chance."

I am new to this level and will "go with the flow". I DO WISH SE sites were more forgiving on vague questions as I know I've had my fare share over the years, but...

### tldr;

What is the best course of action in this?

Comment: _That_ question, to which you refer, is actually really interesting, although badly worded and somewhat broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it takes five close votes and five reopen votes to put a question on hold and reopen a question, respectability. If you think it should be reopened, then vote accordingly. If no one else agrees, no harm done. If others agree, your job is done.

If you're really not sure, it's best to skip it and leave the review to someone else.

Comment: cool, I had no idea if it was 5 to reopen or not (I knew it needed 5 to close). I did skip it at any rate :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not surprised the question was closed:

> hi guys How can I serial monitor repport send the atmega328 and save in chip? thanks.

That's incredibly vague. In fact, it doesn't make sense.

OK, he edited it, but the damage was done. A lot of people didn't understand it, and voted to close it. Not one of them was a moderator, even. So it took 5 close votes to close it. Now he need to improve it enough to get 5 reopen votes.

You are, of course, welcome to cast one of those 5 votes.

Comment: It is a very poorly worded question, if it even rates as a question at all. it's a shame, I'm a massive fan of SE, but more a lurker as my rep shows. These are the sort of questions I wish stack could help users with (well, not this vague, but) given the right push these questions  can pave the way to greater learning. Anyway, it's where it should be :) I didn't cast an open vote, not unless they were really going to try and have a go, but my question was more about the process. I didnt know about the 5 votes to reopen. Thanks again guys

Comment: We are trying to help, but we have to understand the question. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's all good. I understood that too. It was probably a very poorly chosen example on my part. It's a discussion I'd like to take elsewhere, but in essence, sometimes I do wish SE was more "how can I achieve this solution" as opposed to the strict Q&A style that it is. I know it's not. and I'm not debating the issue here and now. Cheers Nick! :)

Comment: @Madivad - personally I agree with you. I have had a few questions closed as not being on topic, when all I was trying to do was get a solution to my problem. We are trying to not be too pedantic here (on Arduino SE) as we know we get a lot of beginners here.